# Cannot downcast an Object into Frame in Java Window Event handling

Tags: windowlistener

I am learning basic event handling in Java.

I am working on Frame Closing method (Implemented from WindowListener). I understand that `getsource()` call returns the object where actual event is taking place. When it downcast to Window, it works fine but when I downcast it to one more level below (to Frame), it doesn't work and gives an error- **Frame cannot be resolved to a type**

In my main class, I am extending Frame.

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    Object objSource= e.getSource();

    //Window objWindow = (Window)objSource;   - It works fine

    Frame objWindow = (Frame)objSource;     //- Why it doesn't work

    objWindow.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `import java.awt.Frame;` package was not imported in code hence it was giving error in closing the Frame window. Above code works perfectly for both `Frame` and `Window` call.